Spinor indices, raising indices of pauli matrices
How do we raise indices for a Pauli matrix. For example let $\left(\sigma^{y}\right)_{a\dot{a}} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. How can I raise the index using 2D levi-civita symbol such that we get $\left(\sigma^{y}\right)_{a}^{\;\;b}$ ? I assume that raising indices of Pauli indices works different compared to GR since levi-civita symbol is not a metric.
My other question is, what is the difference between $\left(\sigma^{y}\right)^{a}_{\;\;\dot{a}}$ and $\left(\sigma^{y}\right)_{a}^{\;\;\dot{a}}$?

Review and also.
